# Fetch multiple links inside foreach loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch-api

I have array of links like so:

```
let array = ['https://1','https://2','https://3']
```

Than i want to loop all elements and run fetch on them. Still fetch is async so i get request more times i deal this problem removing element from array like so:

```
array.forEach((link,index) => {
    fetch(link, {mode: 'no-cors'}).then(function () {
        //more stuff not inportant
    }).catch(e => {
        console.error('error', e);
    });
    array.splice(index,1)
})
```

I wonder is there better solution to solve this ?

Comment: It's not a good practice to mutate an array you iterate. Why do you need this in here?

Comment: You might want to investigate [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to use Promise.all for this, like so:

```
// store urls to fetch in an array
const urls = [
  'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list',
  'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random'
];

// use map() to perform a fetch and handle the response for each url
Promise.all(urls.map(url =>
  fetch(url)
    .then(checkStatus)                 
    .then(parseJSON)
    .catch(logError)
))
.then(data => {
  // do something with the data
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Promise.all()` in this instance.  Start with getting the body from each response. Then do something with the responses after the respective promises are fulfilled:

```
let urls = ['https://1','https://2','https://3']

Promise.all(urls.map(url =>
   // do something with this response like parsing to JSON
   fetch(url,{mode: 'no-cors'}).then(response => response)
)).then(data => {
   // do something with the responses data
})
```

Comment: What is that first `then` for?

Comment: @ScottSauyet I guess we could remove that but you might want to parse the data , I'll add a comment to explain thanks

Answer (score -1):

The responses will be coming in order they finish.

```js
const urls = [1,2,3,4];

// using async await with for loop

const der = async (x) => {
    const f = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${x}`)
    const j = await f.json()
    return j;
};

urls.forEach(async(url) => {console.log(await der(url))});

// using promise all with then method

Promise.all(urls.map(x =>
   fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${x}`).then(response => response.json())
)).then(data => {
   console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: The `forEach` solution is wrong. As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#description), `forEach` does not wait for promises. Since ES18, if you want an asynchronous `for` interation, you should use [`for await...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of).

Comment: when brain becomes brain++